Getting all Weekends for each "Unique ID" between 2 given dates
I have a Table with 3 Columns:

Unique ID - Non Numeric 11 Bytes
Start Date - Date of format 'YYYYMMDD'
End Date - Date of format 'YYYYMMDD'

I intend to get all Weekends falling between the Start & End Date.
I can get the Weekends given 2 Dates as the below query:
with qry as (
  select to_date('20240722', 'yyyymmdd') date1, to_date('20240810', 'yyyymmdd') date2
  from dual
)
select level, date1 + level as CurDate, trunc(date1 + level), trunc(date1 + level,'IW'), add_months(date1,1)
from qry
where trunc(date1 + level) - trunc(date1 + level,'IW') > 5
connect by trunc(date1 + level) < date2

However, I am getting Loop Error when I am trying the Hierarchical Query:
SELECT UNIQUE_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,(START_DATE + LEVELE) AS WEEKEND_DATE
FROM TABLE1
CONNECT BY UNIQUE_ID = PRIOR UNIQUE_ID
AND     (START_DATE + LEVEL) < END_DATE
AND     TRUNC(START_DATE + LEVEL) - TRUNC(START_DATE + LEVEL,'IW') > 5

I guess the statement CONNECT BY UNIQUE_ID = PRIOR UNIQUE_ID is picking up the Parent Row as well which is causing the error.
I tried providing unique Row Number by ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UNIQUE_ID ORDER BY UNIQUE_ID) AS ROW_NUM in conjunction with UNIQUE_ID = PRIOR UNIQUE_ID AND ROW_NUM > 1 but with not desired result.
Query I used:
with req_val(Unique_id,start_date,end_Date) as
(select '105000182','20240710','20240810'
 from dual
 union all
 select '105000871','20240806','20240906'
  from dual
 union all
 select '105001602','20240726','20240826'
  from dual
 union all
 select '105002582','20240727','20240827'
 from dual)
select rownum,Unique_id,start_date,end_Date, (to_date(START_DATE,'yyyymmdd') + level) as weekend_date
from req_val
where trunc(to_date(start_Date,'yyyymmdd') + level) - trunc(to_date(start_date,'yyyymmdd') + level,'IW') > 5
connect by (to_date(start_date,'yyyymmdd') + level) <= to_date(end_date,'yyyymmdd')
and    prior Unique_id = Unique_id

Hence requesting help.

FYI, the DATE data type does not have a format. A format is only used when converting a string (or a number) to a DATE and vice-versa.

You should never store date values as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper DATE values. And why do you store numeric values as string?

Hi, the I/P file is coming as .csv with dates as string. Also, UniqueID can have Characters. My example did not have any.
Thanks

Ok, but then you should convert the values into DATE while import.

The best will be to have a calendar table but you could build it on the fly:
with data(id, start_dat, end_dat) as (
    select '1', to_date('20240722', 'yyyymmdd') date1, to_date('20240810', 'yyyymmdd') date2 union all
    select '2', to_date('20240101', 'yyyymmdd') date1, to_date('20240131', 'yyyymmdd') date2
),
dinterval(min_dat, max_dat) as (
    select min(start_dat), max(end_dat) from data
),
calendar(dat, dow) as (
    select min_dat + level - 1,
        to_number( to_char(min_dat + level -1, 'D') ) 
    from dinterval
    connect by min_dat + level - 1 <= (select max_dat from dinterval)
)
select id, count(case when dow in (6,7) then 1 end) / 2 as c from data d
join calendar c on c.dat between d.start_dat and d.end_dat
group by id
order by id
;

Remain the question from a Sunday to a Saturday, do you want to count 1 weekend or 2 ?

Sunday to a Saturday would be counted as 2.
Thanks

then you have to adapt the calculation of "dinterval" to substract 1 day to the min if a Sunday and add 1 day to max if a Saturday and same logic on d.start_dat and d.end_dat used in the final BETWEEN.

Thanks @p3consulting, this worked.
However, I would like to know for my curiosity is to why the Connect By clause did not work with Unique_ID = PRIOR Unique_ID
